# window title bars are not displaying correctly 13.10 when laptop plugged in

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

[image: Unplugged][image: Plugged in])

As you can see the window title bars are completely messed up (partly transparent or white) when they should be all grey according to the ambiance theme when plugged in. And the weird thing is it seems to almost completely go back to normal when I unplug my laptop. I say almost because if you look closely at the window edges, you can see there is a boarder of pixels around each window doing weird things...

I do have laptop-mode-tools installed and I realize that is probably why things change when unplugged. But when I uninstalled laptop_mode the titles were just messed up all the time and never went back to normal at all.

Also it is only ambiance and radiance themes that are being messed up. High contrast and Adwaita are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it must have been a bug with the opensource drivers in the oibaf ppa because it fixed itself today after updating.

Answer (score -1):

In 13.10, you can run `unity --replace` from a terminal to restart Unity, hopefully getting rid of any errors.

Note that `unity --reset` is not a valid command anymore (as far as I know).

Comment: does not seem to fix anything

Comment: anyother ideas?

Comment: last time I went into this problem (maybe 1 month ago) it solved with `--replace` :(